# Excel - Repeat cell value in intervals

Tags: excel, cell, intervals

I have:

1. some cost values (column 1)
2. year where the cost would occur (column 2)
3. intervals (column 3) at which the costs would repeat after the "first-cost-year".

Please see below for the desired result:

[image]

How to do this in Excel? The method should stop after the final year (i.e. 2029) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your first cell (i.e top row for 2019) is cell D2, try this ...

```
=IF(D$1>=$B2,IF(MOD(D$1-$B2,$C2) = 0,$A2,""),"")
```

[image]

Just fill down and across.